# Product of all ideals of prime norm

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am unsure about the truth of the answer in [How to find all the ideals of a given norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320379/how-to-find-all-the-ideals-of-a-given-norm),

where it is claimed "The ideal (p) is the product of all of the prime ideals of norm a power of p (with multiplicity equal to the ramification index)."

It seems that in $\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$, for example, there are no prime ideals of norm $3$ because $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID and $N(a+ib) = a^2 + b^2 = \pm3, \pm 3i$ is not solvable in $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that $(p)$ is the product of all *prime* ideals of norm a power of $p$. In your example, $(3)$ is the only prime ideal of norm a power of $3$, and so the fact in the answer you linked still holds.

I think you're misunderstanding that some primes are what are called *inert*: this means that they remain prime in the extension.